# Scan for mobile phones?

Tags: detection, gsm, mobile

I'd like to measure queuing time, similar to what they're doing in [Finland](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/11/07/20/2152246/Airport-Queuing-Time-Measured-With-Bluetooth). Instead of detecting bluetooth (which is disabled in most phones) I thought of detecting EDGE/3G.

I'd like to log the following information:

- Phone 1 entered the zone at 14:00 and left at 14:30
- Phone 2 entered the zone at 19:05 and left at 19:30

etc.

1. How do I uniquely identify EDGE/3G/etc phones that enter a zone?
2. Is there a better/easier way to uniquely identify phones entering/exiting a physical location in a manner that allows them to remain anonymous?

By "uniquely identify" I mean I want to be able to differentiate between the same phone entering the zone multiple times versus different phones entering.

By "anonymously" I mean I don't want to record any information that would allow anyone to track down the phone's owner.

**I have no intent, expertise or need to snoop on phone conversations.** I just want to identify phones as they pass by.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out as well. It is my understanding that a phone that is not connected to a tower will intermittently transmit their IMSI which you could passively pick up and uniquely ID the phone. The issue is that when a phone connects to a tower its given a TMSI which is a temporary ID and is frequently changed - to prevent the very thing you are proposing. I am not sure how often these change or if they are encrypted. I am pretty sure the IMSI is not encrypted based on the fact that the tower sets the encryption method and encrypted cell traffic is illegal in some places.

Comment: Damn didn't realize this was 4 years old. You find more out?

Answer (score 1):

In the article you link "Bluetooth Enabled" means discoverable.

In discoverable mode, a Bluetooth device responds to `inquiry` messages with its name and unique ID. This is the feature of Bluetooth allowing it to be tracked.

My limited understanding of GSM/3G/EDGE is that devices can only be tracked by the operator or other holder of the network's encryption keys. If this is your intention, try http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't wish to decrypt phone conversations. How do I find out whether phones can be tracked without decryption? Is there a better place to ask?

Comment: As I said, I don't belive phones can be tracked without the decryption keys